# Sql Server management studio how to auto capitalize

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is there any FREE "build-in" way to capitalize the "keywords" in the SQL 2005/2008 management studio when you write a sql query?

i.e

```
truncate table x
```

should be automatically changed to:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE x
```

Comment: Nothing fancy, but knowing that cntrl-shift-U makes the selection uppercase helps occasionally.

Answer (score 11):

the intellisense in the 2008 management studio will do this as well as long as you are connected to a SQL 2008 database.

You can change the case you prefer to upper or lower under Tools / Options / Text Editor / Transact-SQL / IntelliSense

Comment: in 2014 this doesnt auto correct to capital letters, just outputs caps if I have SQL generate the query. Did this change, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't remember for sure if things have changed since 2008 or not. SSMS 2016 does it for anything that gives you intellisense, but that's mostly for function names rather than keywords. select/truncate/etc. aren't intellisense items, so won't be affected by the intellisense caps setting.

Comment: @blindguy, I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in 'intellisense' in SQL Server 2005 (there is in 2008) but Redgate do an add-in for exactly this and more. It will auto-complete table names, columns, add square brackets, re-format stored procs etc, and it works well:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm

Comment: I love RedGate software. SQL Prompt and Refactor are some of my most heavily used tools.

Comment: but this is paid tool, and the question require FREE tool, as the asker said.

Answer (score 2):

I found a hidden gem for auto upper/lower case formatting and indenting in SSMS that I will forever use. No more "New Query".

Rt-Click table name within Object Explorer | Edit Top 200 Rows | QueryDesigner menu option | Pane | SQL. Write or drop in some ugly, non formatted SQL. QueryDesigner | Verify SQL Syntax will UC reserved words and indent for you.

Comment: Wow, tedious and annoying but it does the trick.  You'd think that since they have the capability, they'd make it just a tiny bit more accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use New Query and type in your SQL in lower case in the editor. To change keywords to upper case, select the SQL then press `Ctrl + Shift + Q`. The Query Designer will open. Highlight the SQL and then right click to bring up menu and choose verify SQL Syntax which will upper case keywords and format the SQL.

Comment: Every sql is not graphically representable. thanks

Answer (score -3):

As far as I can tell, go with some third-party tool, as Microsoft haven't done this request for the past 12 years, they might-not  do it any time soon, I guess it's equal to a shot in the dark to expect this feature from them !

-Sadly, A new SQL Developer :(

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for contributing. 
This is a very old question, so bumping it usually does not bring much of an advantage to the OP.