# Can SQL server automatically capitalize words like FROM and WHERE when building a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, capitalization

What I would really like is to not have to hit the caps lock button as often as I do for a few key words. I know that many just use lower case only but all of the queries we write at the company I work for do this so it would be nice to not have to worry about it as much.

There are probably other issues that would arise from doing this but I kind of just want to give it a shot for a little while if I can. Thank you.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't do that.  That's like asking if a compiler does that.  You need to ask about you Integrated Development Environment.  The thing you actually write your code in.  So, where do you write your queries?  In SQL Server Management Studio?  In Visual Studio?  In Excel?  Inside your C# code?  In Eclipse?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421847/sql-server-management-studio-how-to-auto-capitalize

Comment: Assuming you are working in SSMS you might look at some third party plugins that can make this kind of thing a lot easier. I use SQLPrompt from redgate. It isn't free but it is super handy for lots of things like this.